# Force GAM model fit to be monotonic and go through a fixed point (x0, y0) with R mgcv

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am trying to fit a GAM model to data under two constraints *simultatenously*: (1) the fit is monotonic (increasing), (2) the fit goes through a fixed point, say, `(x0,y0)`.

So far, I managed to have these two constraints work *separately*:

- For (1), based on [mgcv::pcls() documentation examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/0.6-1/topics/pcls), by using `mgcv::mono.con()` to get linear constraints sufficient for monotonicity, and estimate model coefs via `mgcv::pcls()`, using the constraints.
- For (2), based on [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-March/350253.html), by setting the value of spline at knot location x0 to 0 + using offset term in the model formula.

**However, I struggle to combine these two constraints simultaneously.** I *guess* a way to go is `mgcv::pcls()`, but I could work out neither (a) doing a similar trick of setting the value of spline at knot location x0 to 0 + using offset nor (b) setting equality constraint(s) (which I think could yield my (2) constraint setup).

I also note that the approach for setting the value of spline at knot location x0 to 0 for my constrain condition (2) yields weirdly wiggly outcome (as compared to unconstrained GAM fit) -- as showed below.

#### Attempt so far: fit a smooth function to data under two constraints *separately*

Simulate some data

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(runif(100) * 4 - 1)
f <- exp(4*x)/(1+exp(4*x))
y <- f + rnorm(100) * 0.1
dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

GAM unconstrained (for comparison)

```
k <- 13
fit0 <- gam(y ~ s(x, k = k, bs = "cr"), data = dat)
# predict from unconstrained GAM fit
newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(-1, 3, length.out = 1000))
newdata$y_pred_fit0 <- predict(fit0, newdata = newdata)
```

**GAM constrained: (1)** the fit is monotonic (increasing)

```
k <- 13

# Show regular spline fit (and save fitted object)
f.ug <- gam(y~s(x,k=k,bs="cr"))

# explicitly construct smooth term's design matrix
sm <- smoothCon(s(x,k=k,bs="cr"),dat,knots=NULL)[[1]]
# find linear constraints sufficient for monotonicity of a cubic regression spline
# it assumes "cr" is the basis and its knots are provided as input
F <- mono.con(sm$xp)

G <- list(
  X=sm$X,
  C=matrix(0,0,0),  # [0 x 0] matrix (no equality constraints)
  sp=f.ug$sp,       # smoothing parameter estimates (taken from unconstrained model)
  p=sm$xp,          # array of feasible initial parameter estimates
  y=y,           
  w= dat$y * 0 + 1  # weights for data    
)
G$Ain <- F$A        # matrix for the inequality constraints
G$bin <- F$b        # vector for the inequality constraints
G$S <- sm$S         # list of penalty matrices; The first parameter it penalizes is given by off[i]+1
G$off <- 0          # Offset values locating the elements of M$S in the correct location within each penalty coefficient matrix.  (Zero offset implies starting in first location)

p <- pcls(G);       # fit spline (using smoothing parameter estimates from unconstrained fit)

# predict 
newdata$y_pred_fit2 <- Predict.matrix(sm, data.frame(x = newdata$x)) %*% p
# plot
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
lines(y_pred_fit0 ~ x, data = newdata, col = 2, lwd = 2)
lines(y_pred_fit2 ~ x, data = newdata, col = 4, lwd = 2)
```

Blue line: constrained; red line: unconstrained

[image]

**GAM constrained: (2)** fitted go through `(x0,y0)=(-1, -0.1)`

```
k <- 13

## Create a spline basis and penalty
## Make sure there is a knot at the constraint point (here: -1)
knots <- data.frame(x = seq(-1,3,length=k)) 
# explicit construction of a smooth term in a GAM
sm <- smoothCon(s(x,k=k,bs="cr"), dat, knots=knots)[[1]]

## 1st parameter is value of spline at knot location -1, set it to 0 by dropping
knot_which <- which(knots$x == -1)
X <- sm$X[, -knot_which]                  ## spline basis
S <- sm$S[[1]][-knot_which, -knot_which]  ## spline penalty
off <- dat$y * 0 + (-0.1)                   ## offset term to force curve through (x0, y0)

## fit spline constrained through (x0, y0)
gam_1 <- gam(y ~ X - 1 + offset(off), paraPen = list(X = list(S)))

# predict (add offset of -0.1)
newdata_tmp <- Predict.matrix(sm, data.frame(x = newdata$x))
newdata_tmp <- newdata_tmp[, -knot_which]    
newdata$y_pred_fit1 <- (newdata_tmp %*% coef(gam_1))[, 1] + (-0.1)

# plot
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
lines(y_pred_fit0 ~ x, data = newdata, col = 2, lwd = 2)
lines(y_pred_fit1 ~ x, data = newdata, col = 3, lwd = 2)
# lines at cross of which the plot should go throught
abline(v=-1, col = 3); abline(h=-0.1, col = 3)
```

Green line: constrained; red line: unconstrained

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I think you could augment the data vectors `x` and `y` with `(x0, y0)` and then put a (really) high weight on the first observation (i.e. add a weight vector to your `G` list).

Alternatively to the simple weighting strategy, we can write the quadratic programming problem starting from the results of the preliminary smoothing. This is illustrated in the second R-code below (in this case I used p-spline smoothers, see Eilers and Marx 1991).

Hope this helps a bit ([a similar problem is discussed here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462343/smoothing-splines-with-a-boundary-constraint/462589#462589)).

### Rcode example 1 (weight strategy)

```
set.seed(123)
N = 100
x <- sort(runif(N) * 4 - 1)
f <- exp(4*x)/(1+exp(4*x))
y <- f + rnorm(N) * 0.1
x = c(-1, x)
y = c(-0.1, y)
dat = data.frame(x = x, y= y)

k <- 13
fit0 <- gam(y ~ s(x, k = k, bs = "cr"), data = dat)
# predict from unconstrained GAM fit
newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(-1, 3, length.out = 1000))
newdata$y_pred_fit0 <- predict(fit0, newdata = newdata)

k <- 13

# Show regular spline fit (and save fitted object)
f.ug <- gam(y~s(x,k=k,bs="cr"))

# explicitly construct smooth term's design matrix
sm <- smoothCon(s(x,k=k,bs="cr"),dat,knots=NULL)[[1]]
# find linear constraints sufficient for monotonicity of a cubic regression spline
# it assumes "cr" is the basis and its knots are provided as input
F <- mono.con(sm$xp)

G <- list(
X=sm$X,
C=matrix(0,0,0),  # [0 x 0] matrix (no equality constraints)
sp=f.ug$sp,       # smoothing parameter estimates (taken from unconstrained model)
p=sm$xp,          # array of feasible initial parameter estimates
y=y,           
w= c(1e8, 1:N * 0 + 1)  # weights for data    
)
G$Ain <- F$A        # matrix for the inequality constraints
G$bin <- F$b        # vector for the inequality constraints
G$S <- sm$S         # list of penalty matrices; The first parameter it penalizes is given by off[i]+1
G$off <- 0          # Offset values locating the elements of M$S in the correct location within each penalty coefficient matrix.  (Zero offset implies starting in first location)

p <- pcls(G);       # fit spline (using smoothing parameter estimates from unconstrained fit)

# predict 
newdata$y_pred_fit2 <- Predict.matrix(sm, data.frame(x = newdata$x)) %*% p
# plot
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
lines(y_pred_fit0 ~ x, data = newdata, col = 2, lwd = 2)
lines(y_pred_fit2 ~ x, data = newdata, col = 4, lwd = 2)
abline(v = -1)
abline(h = -0.1)
```

[image]

```
rm(list = ls())
library(mgcv)
library(pracma)
library(colorout)

set.seed(123)
N   = 100
x   = sort(runif(N) * 4 - 1)
f   = exp(4*x)/(1+exp(4*x))
y   = f + rnorm(N) * 0.1
x0  = -1
y0  = -0.1 
dat = data.frame(x = x, y= y)

k = 50
# Show regular spline fit (and save fitted object)
f.ug = gam(y~s(x,k=k,bs="ps"))

# explicitly construct smooth term's design matrix
sm = smoothCon(s(x,k=k,bs="ps"), dat,knots=NULL)[[1]]

# Build quadprog to estimate the coefficients 
scf = sapply(f.ug$smooth, '[[', 'S.scale')
lam = f.ug$sp / scf
Xp  = rbind(sm$X, sqrt(lam) * f.ug$smooth[[1]]$D)  
yp  = c(dat$y, rep(0, k - 2))
X0  = Predict.matrix(sm, data.frame(x = x0))
sm$deriv = 1
X1 = Predict.matrix(sm, data.frame(x = dat$x))
coef_mono = pracma::lsqlincon(Xp, yp, Aeq = X0, beq = y0, A = -X1, b = rep(0, N))

# fitted values
fit = sm$X %*% coef_mono
sm$deriv = 0
xf = seq(-1, 3, len = 1000)
Xf = Predict.matrix(sm, data.frame(x = xf))
fine_fit = Xf %*% coef_mono

# plot
par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar = c(3,3,3,3))
plot(dat$x, dat$y, pch = 1, main= 'Data and fit')
lines(dat$x, f.ug$fitted, lwd = 2, col = 2)
lines(dat$x, fit, col = 4, lty = 1, lwd = 2)
lines(xf, fine_fit, col = 3, lwd = 2, lty = 2)
abline(h = -0.1)
abline(v = -1)

plot(dat$x, X1 %*% coef_mono, type = 'l', main = 'Derivative of the fit', lwd = 2)
abline(h = 0.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Gi_F. thank you for your excellent answer. I'd like to add that I checked out both approaches on the actual data set I have in the project where this problem occurred (6M observations), and the 1st approach did fly. Thanks a ton!!

I spoke with a co-author and we are eager to highlight your contribution in the Acknowledgements section in the manuscript. If this sounds good to you, would you be willing to suggest a contact info to you, or use my email (can be found on my SO profile bio) and contact me? This is to learn your name/affiliation to put to the Acknowledgements.

Comment: Some technical comments to the toy example above: in (2) approach, to get predictions on data set of choice, get the newdata X matrix from `sm` object  anywhere *before*  `sm$deriv = 1` line (i.e. `newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(-1, 3, length.out = 1000)); newdataX <- Predict.matrix(sm, data.frame(x = newdata$x))`), then predict with `newdataX %*% coef_mono`.

Comment: Further notes: the (2) approach yielded a predicted values on my above `newdata` which were not exactly monotonic (although the un-monotonic difference occured at 6-th decimal place); I also ran into problems with `chol(sm$S[[1]])` part in my real data example.

Comment: Hi, happy to hear that strategy (1) worked well for you. About strategy (2) I made some changes: the `chol` issue should be solved. I am not an expert user of `mgcv` package so I had to dig a bit to find the right penalty matrix ans scaling for the smoothing parameter (`lam` now). About the 6-decimals issue, I think you are looking at the first diff of the fit. However, the fist derivative of a spline fit is equal to $B' a$ where $B'$ is the first derivative B-spline bases, `X1` in the code and $a$ the vec of spline coeff (I added a plot of the deriv...min value ~ -1e-16)

Answer (score 1):

The following package seems to implement what you are looking for:

> The proposed shape constrained smoothing has been incorporated into generalized
> additive models with a mixture of unconstrained and shape restricted smooth terms
> (mono-GAM). [...]
>
> The proposed modelling approach has been implemented in an R package `monogam`.
> The model setup is the same as in `mgcv(gam)` with the addition of shape constrained
> smooths. In order to be consistent with the unconstrained GAM, the package provides
> key functions similar to those associated with `mgcv(gam)`.

- [Additive models with shape constraints](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/40031478.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! I have checked out Natalya Pya's `scam` R package (to my understanding, "the" CRAN package with methods presented in the thesis linked). I saw it does provide a set of shape constraints (8 different types) and returns a convenient gam object (contrary to `mgcv::pcls` + `mgcv::mono.con()` way), but I didn't see a way to use it to get fit going through a fixed point